# How to undo the rotation of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Here is an example of an image. The object in the image seems to be rotated. How do I undo the rotation of it?

[image]

Comment: you can use opencv's minAreaRect to approximate a contour angle. Might work in some cases, but not in all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the contours in the image than convert them to a rotate rect using opencv. the rotate rect will provide you the angle. all you need to do than is to rotate the image using that angle. The code is attached below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("opencv_task.png",0)
con , _ = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
minRect = cv2.minAreaRect(con[0])

## uncomment these if you want to draw a rectangle
# box = cv2.boxPoints(minRect)
# box = np.intp(box) #np.intp: Integer used for indexing (same as C ssize_t; normally either int32 or int64)
# cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (255,255,0))

(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
(cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)

#minRect[2] is the angle of the rotate rectangle
# rotate our image by minRect[2] degrees around the center of the image

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), minRect[2], 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h))
cv2.imshow("Rotated", rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the output sample is attached here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the image library from `PIL` there is a `rotate` method. Here goes an example of function that could help you

```js
from PIL import Image

def rotar(a,t): #a es el nombre de la imagen, t son los grados en deg
    colorImage  = Image.open(a)
    rotated     = colorImage.rotate(t, expand=True)
    rotated.save('rotated.png')
```